# Problemas con el ajuste de tamaño de una imagen utilizando react-zoom-pan-pinch y Next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, nextjs

Estoy teniendo dificultades para lograr que una imagen se ajuste correctamente al tamaño de un contenedor en mi aplicación, utilizando react-zoom-pan-pinch y Next.js. He intentado varias soluciones, pero ninguna parece funcionar correctamente.

1. La imagen no cambia de tamaño incluso cuando establezco la altura y el ancho a la imagen y a cada uno de los componentes y etiquetas que envuelven la imagen.
2. No tengo estilos adicionales lo que se ve es tal cual lo tengo.
3. la imagen mide ancho: 3000px alto: 702px

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
import Image from "next/image";

const ZoomableImage = ({ imageUrl }) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{ height: "800px", width: "90%", backgroundColor: "lightgray" }}
    >
      <TransformWrapper>
        <TransformComponent>
          <div style={{ position: "relative", width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
            <Image
              src={imageUrl}
              alt="test"
              layout="responsive"
              height={800}
              width="100%"
              objectFit="contain"
            />
          </div>
        </TransformComponent>
      </TransformWrapper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ZoomableImage;
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar estos problemas y lograr que la imagen se ajuste correctamente al tamaño del contenedor mientras se mantiene la relación de aspecto original y se permite el zoom y el desplazamiento utilizando react-zoom-pan-pinch?

como se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como quiero que se vea:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando `nextjs` puedes usar `tailwind CSS`.

Con este ejemplo se puede resolver el problema que muestras con las imagenes en tu pregunta, lo del zoom tendrías que implementarlo por separado.

---

Se usa el div como contenedor y que sea de 10 px, horizontal y vertical (opcional segun el caso de uso):

```
h-10 w-14
```

se centra horizontalmente (opcional):

```
mx-auto
```

se oculta el contenido de la imagen que queda por encima del contenedor:

```
overflow-hidden
```

---

Demo que puedes ajustar a tu caso de uso:

```js
function App(){
  
  return (
  <React.Fragment>
   <div>Ocultando overflow</div>
   <div className="container mx-auto overflow-hidden h-10 w-14">
      <img src="https://cdn.waifu.im/7610.jpg"></img>
   </div>
    <div>Sin ocultar overflow</div>
   <div>
      <img src="https://cdn.waifu.im/7610.jpg"></img>
   </div>
     
  </React.Fragment>)
  
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
      <App></App>  
    )
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```